# Appending dictionary to list of dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

Basically coming up with the last reference to the dict with the modified values for all appending instead of each new dict. So it should be 1-3 for each event.Also using a while loop appends nothing.

```
    events=[{'start':{'dateTime':0},'end':{'dateTime':0}},]
    start_dates=[
        {'start':{'date':1},'end':{'date':1}},
        {'start':{'date':2},'end':{'date':2}},
        {'start':{'date':3},'end':{'date':3}},
        
        ]
        
    for date in start_dates:
        print(date)
        
        del date['start']['date']
        del date['end']['date']
        
        for i in range(1,3):
            new = dict(date)
            new['start']['dateTime']=str(i)
            new['end']['dateTime']=str(i)
            print(new)
            events.append(new.copy())
    print(events)
```

Outputs:

```
    [{'start': {'dateTime': 0}, 'end': {'dateTime': 0}}, 
     {'start': {'dateTime': '2'}, 'end': {'dateTime': '2'}}, 
     {'start': {'dateTime': '2'}, 'end': {'dateTime': '2'}}, 
     {'start': {'dateTime': '2'}, 'end': {'dateTime': '2'}}, 
     {'start': {'dateTime': '2'}, 'end': {'dateTime': '2'}}, 
     {'start': {'dateTime': '2'}, 'end': {'dateTime': '2'}}, 
     {'start': {'dateTime': '2'}, 'end': {'dateTime': '2'}}]
```

Expected:

```
    [{'start': {'dateTime': 0}, 'end': {'dateTime': 0}}, 
     {'start': {'dateTime': '1'}, 'end': {'dateTime': '1'}}, 
     {'start': {'dateTime': '2'}, 'end': {'dateTime': '2'}},
     {'start': {'dateTime': '3'}, 'end': {'dateTime': '3'}}]
```

Comment: What exactly is the question?

Comment: Being brief and concise is a good thing, but this is a bit too short. What exactly are you asking? How is what you're getting not what you're expecting? Can you give an example of the output you would have expected?

Comment: How would I append 3 different dicts into a dictionary list after modifying each dictionary. It's just getting the last loop value instead of all of them.

Comment: You are reusing the inner dicts (like `{"date": 1}`) in your loop.`dict(date)` makes a copy of the outer dict, but the inner dicts are references to the same object.  If you want to continue with this idea, you need to make a deep copy: `from copy import deepcopy` then `new = dict(deepcopy(date))`. FWIW...`deepcopy()` is convenient but not particularly fast.

Comment: Ok the deepcopy on the date worked.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to reuse the inner dicts - you are deleting the structure anyways. Unless there is a specific reason for deepcopy.

There is an indentation problem as well.

```
events=[{'start':{'dateTime':0},'end':{'dateTime':0}},]
start_dates=[
    {'start':{'date':1},'end':{'date':1}},
    {'start':{'date':2},'end':{'date':2}},
    {'start':{'date':3},'end':{'date':3}},
    ]


for i in range(0,3):
    new = {}
    new['start'] = {'dateTime': str(i+1)}
    new['end'] = {'dateTime' : str(i+1)}
    events.append(new)

for event in events:
    print(event)
```

Output is

```
{'start': {'dateTime': 0}, 'end': {'dateTime': 0}}
{'start': {'dateTime': '1'}, 'end': {'dateTime': '1'}}
{'start': {'dateTime': '2'}, 'end': {'dateTime': '2'}}
{'start': {'dateTime': '3'}, 'end': {'dateTime': '3'}}
```

Comment: The structure is much larger then this there are more variables in it. deepcopy was necessary here.